# StencilJS component on Vue 1.x project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, stenciljs

I'm trying to integrate a stencil.js component with an existing Vue 1.x project. I've done the same thing in a Vue 2.x project and [`ignoredElements`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements) config. Is there an equivalent to such thing in Vue 1.x or is the integration done differently?

(I read [this documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-elements-interop.html#autonomous-custom-elements) Vue 1.x is missing, maybe it's not possible?)

The stencil package is stored in a private registry and it is not ideal to serve it by adding it into the index.html

As of now, I'm unable to see my component and the following warning is outputted to the console.

`Unknown custom element: <test-component> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

Comment: The `ignoredElements` config was added in Vue 2.0.0, so the only option I see is to patch Vue 1.x yourself to add that support (it would only take a few LOC). You could use [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to automatically apply your patch.

Comment: If they are hosting it on a platform, they will need to patch 1.x and host it somewhere public tho.

Comment: @kissu The warning is only supposed to display in `development` mode, and if they're tree-shaking their `production` build, the patch would be culled. And I assume they'd only be hosting a `production` build, in which case there would be no warning anyway.

Comment: Yep, exactly as @tony19 said, the error is only in development and I do believe that you've given me a very valid workaround.